# stop() caller not working properly

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am making a brick breaker game with three frames. The first frame is the start screen, the second frame is the game itself, and the third frame is the "game over" screen (with a try again button). When I hit "Start game" the program jumps to the second frame and stops. If you fail to hit the ball with the racket, the program jumps to frame three.

My problem occurs here, because the program instantly jumps to the second frame again. Any idea why the `stop();` caller fails to work? I have tried to remove all content from the last frame (except for the `stop();` caller), but it still just skips back to frame 2.

I really can't figure out why this is happening. I am using Adobe Flash Professional CC. The only actionscript on frame 3 are "stop();". This is the entire code block on frame 2:

```js
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
trace(currentFrame);

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);

var rackert: bar = new bar();
rackert.name = "rackert";
rackert.y = 740;
rackert.x = 640;
addChild(rackert);

var ball: circle = new circle();
ball.y = 80;
ball.x = 640;
addChild(ball);
var ballXSpeed: Number = 12; //X Speed of the Ball
var ballYSpeed: Number = 12; //Y Speed of the Ball

function keyDown(e: KeyboardEvent) {
  var key: uint = e.keyCode;
  var step: uint = 35;
  switch (key) {
    case Keyboard.LEFT:
      if (rackert.x > 0) {
        var myTween: Tween = new Tween(rackert, "x", Regular.easeOut, rackert.x, rackert.x - step, 0.2, true);
      } else rackert.x = 0;
      break;
    case Keyboard.RIGHT:
      if (rackert.x + rackert.width < 1000) {
        var myTween2: Tween = new Tween(rackert, "x", Regular.easeOut, rackert.x, rackert.x + step, 0.2, true);
      } else rackert.x = 1000 - rackert.width;
      break;
  }
}
var gameOver: Boolean = false;

function moveBall(event: Event): void {
  ball.x += ballXSpeed;
  ball.y += ballYSpeed;
  if (ball.x >= 1000 - (ball.width / 2)) {
    ballXSpeed *= -1;
  }
  if (ball.x <= 0 + (ball.width / 2)) {
    ballXSpeed *= -1;
  }
  if (ball.y >= stage.stageHeight) {
    if (gameOver == false) {
      gotoAndStop(3);
      this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);
      stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
      gameOver = true;
      rackert.visible = false;
    }
  }
  if (ball.y <= 22) {
    ballYSpeed *= -1;
  }
  if (ball.hitTestObject(rackert)) {
    calcBallAngle();
  }
}

function calcBallAngle(): void {
  var ballPosition: Number = ball.x - rackert.x;
  trace("Position: " + ballPosition);
  var hitPercent: Number = (ballPosition / (rackert.width - ball.width)) - .7;
  trace("percent: " + hitPercent);
  ballXSpeed = hitPercent * 10;
  ballYSpeed *= -1;
}

function getRandom(min: Number, max: Number): Number {
  return min + (Math.random() * (max - min));
}
```

Comment: Not seeing anything in your code sample where you're calling stop() anywhere. Is it just in a frame script on the frame you're jumping to?

Comment: Yes, thats right. The code snippet is fram frame 2, and the stop() caller is actionscript on frame 3.

Comment: Currently the only code on frame 3 are "stop();" (and with no elements on stage).

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
if (gameOver == false) {
    gotoAndPlay(3); //gotoAndPlay(); caller
    gameOver = true;
    rackert.visible = false;
}
```

To:

```
if (gameOver == false) {
    gotoAndStop(3); //gotoAndPlay(); caller
    gameOver = true;
    rackert.visible = false;
}
```

Difference is [goToAndStop()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndStop%28%29). The default behavior is to "loop" an animation, so you tell it to go to frame 3 (last frame) and it "plays" through that frame back around to 1, then 2, where you most likely have a frame script that calls stop(); to stop the play head.

***Update***
I believe you that you're calling stop(); in frame 3. It seems like it should work and indeed it actually is, it's just not working on the object that you're expecting it to work on. Since you're using a frame script, stop(); is being called on the InteractiveObject who's scope the frame script is inside of. Let me clarify.

Frame 3 Of Stage
   -> Child on frame three called FrameScriptsArePITA
       -> Double click FrameScriptsArePITA and write a frame script "stop()", the script will do nothing but stop FrameScriptsArePITA from playing.

Watch your scope. That's part of why frame scripts are... best to avoid. Using your own DocumentClass and hooking everything in your design view into corresponding classes will make things easier to solve in AS3.

Comment: I have tried this too but the excact same thing happens :/

Comment: @MattisTrygstad try doing stage.goToAndStop() or parent.goToAndStop(). I'm just taking stabs in the dark now we'll need to see more code. It's definitely an issue with the scope of your scripts.

Comment: When I try stage.gotoAndStop(); i get the compiler error: "Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 2, Line 53, Column 10 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndStop through a reference with static type flash.display:Stage."

Comment: @MattisTrygstad Yeah I was wrong about calling it on stage, it's not of type MovieClip. It's been a long time so my bad. But as I said, you'll need to post more code because now the post is going to degenerate into wild guesses which isn't good for anyone. Definitely go over your scope again. Compare where you're calling stop() in frame 2 (and it works) to where and how you're calling stop in frame 3.

Comment: I have struggled with this issue for a long time, and i can't seem to figure it out. I have posted all of my code on frame 2 on the original post.

Comment: @MattisTrygstad that can't be all of the code because there's nothing anywhere in there about stopping on frame 2. What I can see is that your logic to switch frames is happening inside of an OnEnterFrame handler. It's kind of bad to stuff game logic in there since it just gets called forever as long as something is rendering. Where you change it to frame 3, add this: "this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);

Comment: I have used the gotoAndStop(); caller on frame 1, so i did not seem to need the stop(); caller on frame 2. Now i tried to add: "this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);", but that did not work either. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks for the help this far!

Comment: @MattisTrygstad something doesn't add up. You're stopping play at frame 3 explicitly twice. There then absolutely must be some code that's forcing play after that.

Comment: Ok, it looks like i found the issue! I have a time function on frame 1. When i used removeEventListener on this function when i skip to the next frame, it solved my problem. I would assume it is smart to remove all timer events when their not used? Thanks, now i finally can continue my work!

Comment: @MattisTrygstad yes you should always be cleaning up anything including event listeners as they can even interfere with the garbage collector and cause memory leaks. Glad I could help. Don't forget to upvote if you found my post helpful and choose an answer to mark as correct. Since the issue was found by you, consider posting your own answer and marking it as correct when the system lets you (24 hours I believe).

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the issue. I had a timer event on frame 1, which caused the bug. I simply used removeEventListener for the timer function where i skip to frame 2. As *Technick Empire* said, you should always be cleaning up anything including even listeners as they can even interfere with the garbage collector and cause memory leaks.